# ... is no accessor method

Tags: java, spring

I'm currently learning the ropes of Spring.
I tried to *autowire* a method parameter like so:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String something(@Autowire AnInterface ai) {
    ai.doSomething();
    return "/";
}
```

With the following interfaces and classes:

```
@Component
public interface AnInterface {
    void doSomething();
}

@Component
public class Implementation implements AnInterface {
    @Autowired private AnotherInterface ai;

    public Implementation() { ; }

    public Implementation(AnotherInterface ai) {
        this.ai = ai;
    }

    public void setAi(AnotherInterface ai) {
        this.ai = ai;
    }

   @Override
   public void doSomething() {
       System.out.println(ai.hello());

   }
}

@Component
public interface AnotherInterface {
    String hello();
}

@Component
public class AnotherImplementation implements AnotherInterface {

    @Override
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

However, when calling the controller's method, I get an `IllegalArgumentException`:
`Invoked method public abstract void AnInterface.doSomething() is no accessor method!`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you run this code?? I think it will generate compile time error.

Comment: Yeah, it works for me.
However I may have made an error while copying the code..
What error do you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot autowire component that way, try this:

```
@Autowire AnInterface ai;

@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String something() {
    ai.doSomething();
    return "/";
}
```

Comment: Ok, that worked. Thank you!
It may a little off the mark, but why is that?

Comment: @rbgm, spring beans are initialized when application starts, the method will be invoked on application running, at that time point, its already too late..